# scanner not working properly inside if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

This code prompts the user to confirm a booking by typing Y or N (yes/no). If they type y or Y it calls a method `setBooked()` which basically just sets a `boolean` variable "booked" to "true". The `isBooked()` just returns that `boolean` value so I could test the before/after to see if it actually worked.

The actual code does work just not as I expected, it will immediately work properly if you type "y" but if you type anything else it will prompt you again, and again work if you type "y" but this time if you type anything else it just stops and moves on to the next "customer" (method is called about 8 times)

So basically is there a reason that it is prompting the user twice instead of just evaluating what they type the first time for "y" OR "Y"?

```
System.out.println(customer.isBooked());
System.out.println( "Confirm booking for " + customer.getName() + "(Y/N)");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

if (scan.nextLine().equals("y") || scan.nextLine().equals("Y"))
    customer.setBooked();

System.out.println("Booked");
System.out.println(customer.isBooked());
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`#equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29)

Use `scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y")` instead, as [`||`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) will go and check both the conditions as you will be prompted for `nextLine()` twice.

If you want user to keep asking for input if user enters wrong input you should use loop and prompt until condition gets satisfied.

***For Example***

```
     do {
         System.out.println("Type 'y' OR 'Y' to Exit!");
         if(s.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            customer.setBooked();
            break;
         }
      } while(true);
```

Comment: ahh. `equalsIgnoreCase()` *damn it* ~~ :P

Answer (score 4):

It is prompting *twice*, because you are *asking* it to prompt *twice*.

here : `if (scan.nextLine().equals("y") || scan.nextLine().equals("Y"))`
You are calling `scan.nextLine()` two times.

Change your code to :

```
String s = scan.nextLine();
s=s.toLowerCase(); // change "Y" to "y" . Cleaner code.

if(s.equals("y")){
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using following code:

```
System.out.println(customer.isBooked());
System.out.println( "Confirm booking for " + customer.getName() + "(Y/N)");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean flag = scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y");
if (flag)
    customer.setBooked();
System.out.println("Booked");
System.out.println(customer.isBooked());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `scan.nextLine()` twice in the condition, using an OR. This means that if the left side is not true, then it will continue to the right side. However if it is true, then the OR will be true and does not need to evaluate the right side. That is why if when they enter `y` the first time it only asks for it once, but otherwise it asks for it twice.

If you only want it to ask for it once, then instead of doing that assign the value of `scan.nextLine()` to a variable and use that variable in the if statement.

```
String result = scan.nextLine();
if (result.equals("y") || result.equals("Y")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are calling two times

```
 scan.nextLine().equals("y") || scan.nextLine().equals("Y") //2 scan.nextLine()
```

Change your code to

```
 String line=scan.nextLine();
 if ("y".equals(line) ||"Y".equals(line)) // avoid NullPointerException too
```

Or use `equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
 if("y".equalsIgnoreCase(scan.nextLine())) // avoid NullPointerException too
```

Comment: I doubt that call of `Scanner#nextLine` throws a `NullPointerException` unless the underlying input stream breaks abruptly but this would mean there's an external cause that will break the application.

Answer (score 0):

You are stating it should prompt twice here:

```
if (scan.nextLine().equals("y") || scan.nextLine().equals("Y"))
```

by calling `scan.nextLine()` twice.

What you could do is the following:

```
...
String next = scan.nextLine();    

if (next.equals("y") || next.equals("Y"))
...
```